# sending a $id variable through hidden  input tag

Tags: php, html

I have an input tag inside a form as below

- I don't know if I should place the variable $id through the value property of the input tag
- i don't remember but I need that value to the URL so I can pick it up after form submission.

  ```
   <input type="hidden" id="parent_comment" name="comments" value="'.$id.'" />
  ```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier (and more secure) to use `$_SESSION`?

Comment: of course, the only thins is that I am using session for $user loging script already don't know if I can send another session variable.

Comment: $_SESSION is an array and will hold as many (or few) values as you awnt.

Comment: @Marc and @Brad how can I send the session variable $id with the form submission as well?

Comment: ok I did't see your comment MArc below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how you would embed a value in a form. If you want the value to be tamper-proof, then consider encrypting it somehow (http://php.net/mcrypt for one), so that it's meaningless garbage on the client, but easily transformed back to a useful value on the server.

You could store it in the session on the server, but if the user has multiple copies of the form open, the stored value would get stomped on and submitting form copy A would probably get copy B's id value.

As for retrieving the value, it'd be in `$_GET['comments']` or `$_POST['comments']`, depending on how you submit the form.

Comment: and to send it ? as a Session variable? that $_GET['comment'] or $_POST['comments'] were written by you in your answer refering to the input tags I put above? I want to know if it is ok sending that variable $id through the value property like I do above.

Comment: There's two ways to send data via a form. input-type tags (input/select/textarea), or as a query parameter in the form's action attribute. So yes, using a hidden form field is entirely acceptable.

Comment: Marc i think sending the variables will just not work, I have a jquery that hide the responses comment and then slidetoggle it when click on the <a>comment</a> if clicked the a tag it will slidetoggle down the form. I want to know how comment a tag will know which comment is it responding too? is it ok to have a data-parent=$id inside the a tag so that when slidetoggle it knows what comment is being reposed. because before sending the input hidden field the form have to know who is it responding too? give me a suggestion

Comment: I don't know the structure of your html, but you could embed a hidden input field in each comment with the comment's ID, and use jquery selectors to retrieve its value. Or at the time you generate the html embed the ID in dom storage/data, etc... lots of alternatives.